# Is hyperbolic $n$-space $\mathbb{H}^n$ the universal cover of every hyperbolic manifold?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, covering-spaces

I was under the impression that any hyperbolic manifold (finite volume or not) had $\mathbb{H}^n$ as its universal cover, but on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_manifold) it is suggested that this only true for closed hyperbolic manifolds.

In that case, what is the universal cover of a noncompact hyperbolic manifold, such as an infinite volume hyperbolic manifold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important assumption is completeness, not compactness. The key fact is that every *complete*, connected, simply connected hyperbolic manifold is isometric to $\mathbb{H}^n$.

This implies that the universal cover of any *complete*, connected hyperbolic manifold is isometric to $\mathbb{H}^n$, since a Riemannian cover of a complete manifold must also be complete (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863314/when-is-the-universal-cover-of-a-riemannian-manifold-complete?rq=1)). In particular, this is also true for compact connected hyperbolic manifolds, since compact Riemannian manifolds are complete.

Edit: Thanks to Lee Mosher for pointing out in the comments that it is *not* true that the universal cover of any connected hyperbolic manifold is isometric to an open submanifold of $\mathbb{H}^n$.

Comment: The statement in your parenthetical remark is not true. For instance, if $x \in \mathbb{H}^2$ then the universal cover of $\mathbb{H}^2 - \{x\}$ is not isometric to any open submanifold of $\mathbb{H}^2$.

Comment: @Lee Mosher - Interesting point. I might edit my answer once I understand that example better. Is there another way to describe the universal cover of $\mathbb{H}^2 - \{x\}$ in familiar terms? It must be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, but what more can be said about the geometry?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{H}^2 - \{x\}$ is a topological open annulus, its universal cover is indeed homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. The universal cover is not metrically complete, and its metric completion is obtained by adding a single point, which is a limit point of all lifts of all rays in $\mathbb{H}^2$ based at $\{x\}$. I think of that limit point intuitively as a point with total angle $2 \pi \infty$. Also, one can think of the completion as a branched cover of $\mathbb{H}^2$, infinitely branched over $x$.

Comment: @LeeMosher If a hyperbolic manifold is not complete, is its universal cover still conformally equivalent to $\mathbb{H}^n$, or at least diffeomorphic?

Comment: That may be an interesting question, but burying a question in a comment to an answer is not a good practice on stackexchange.